# USB Devices Disabled when no devices are connected

Tags: macos, imac, usb, power

using **iMac 5K OS 10.10.3**

When there are **no USB devices** connected to iMac, it keeps showing this.
[image]

I tried **SMC resetting**, booting through **Safe Mode**, and nothing is working to make this alert go away.

Has anyone had the same experience?

Comment: could you turn off the Bluetooth, the Dropbox and that Truck ?

Comment: Dropbox and the truck icon (Transmit) would in no way affect USB connections.

Comment: turning off bluetooth will make no input devices available. dropbox and truck can get out of the bar, but it would not affect the issue to be solve. but I'm so desperate, give it a try. NOPE!

Comment: Can you check inside the USB ports to make sure there's nothing inside them that could be screwing them up?

Comment: Also, did you try a PRAM reset?

Comment: @user24601 yes, I saw some posts on the web, checked the port with lights, nothings hanging or bent. no interference at all.

Comment: @user24601 pram reset? i have to look it up and try. no, i havent't. thanks, i will try and get back here.

Comment: @handicop Here are [Apple's instructions](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18761?locale=en_US).

Comment: If the pram doesn't clear the issue, try the NVRAM. https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204063

Comment: @bret7600 They're the same thing. From your link: "Resetting NVRAM on Intel-based Macs using the same key combination is like resetting PRAM."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. None of apple technical support instructions worked.
2. Called for Apple Care Service
3. Technician came with a brand new mother board
4. Replaced and problem fixed.

So basically it was hardware failure, which can't be answered here since the board was taken.

Answer (score 1):

MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012)
2.6 GHz Intel Core i7
8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

I just want to say I have the same problem, and Apple Store says it is indeed a hardware problem (and quite pricey to fix).

One USB port never works now, the other one is on and off - that message just pops up now and then.

Solution: If it becomes worse, I will get a thunderbolt->USB adaptor.